# Refresh Token Expiration time Google calendar

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

Can any one please tell me the expiration time for Refresh token generation through OAuth2. Actually it usually returns 2 parameter access token and refresh token. We used refresh token in order to generate a new access toke if access token get expired. But Google Calendar Version3, i am using refresh token in order to call the calendar API. But here i am getting a problem that token get expires. So can any one please suggest me what can i do when token get expires. According to me there is no expiration time for refresh token. Kindly check the code below for creation of calendar service using refresh token :-

```
 private CalendarService CreateService(string token)
{        
    KeyValuePair<string, string> credentials = Common.Get3LOCredentials();
    var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description);
    provider.ClientIdentifier = credentials.Key;
    provider.ClientSecret = credentials.Value;
    var auth = new Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, (p) => GetAuthorization(provider, token));
    CalendarService service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        Authenticator = auth,
        ApiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIkey"].ToString(),
        GZipEnabled = false
    });       
    return service;
}

private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg, String Refreshtoken)
{
    IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { CalendarService.Scopes.Calendar.GetStringValue() });
    state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
    state.RefreshToken = Refreshtoken;        
    return state;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Refresh Tokens do not expire but they can be revoked. You, the token handler can [revoke the token yourself programatically](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke) or the end user can [revoke the token in their account settings](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/41236?hl=en). Make sure you are properly [using the refresh token to get a new access token](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline) and you're not attempting to use an access token that has expired.

Can you edit your question to show the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Thanks for our reply. Instead of using access token i am directly using refresh token for creating calendar service. Previously it was working fine. Kindly check the code in my answer, how i am creating the calendar service using refresh token.