# Could not load type 'Google.Apis.Requests.IErrorResponseHandler' from assembly 'Google.Apis'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I am Google Auth api Calendar in .net. I have copied the code from this link:[Refresh Token Expiration time Google calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715909/refresh-token-expiration-time-google-calendar)
Could not load type 'Google.Apis.Requests.IErrorResponseHandler' from assembly 'Google.Apis, Version=1.6.0.16897, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

[image]

Here is my code:

```
private CalendarService CreateService(string token)
    {
        //KeyValuePair<string, string> credentials = Ninject.Web.Common.Get3LOCredentials();
        var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, this.clientID, this.ClientSecret);
        //provider.ClientIdentifier = clientID;
        //provider.ClientSecret = clientSecret;
        var auth = new Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, (p) => GetAuthorization(provider, token));
        CalendarService service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            Authenticator = auth,
            ApiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[this.APIkey].ToString(),
            GZipEnabled = false
        });
        return service;
    }

    private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg, String Refreshtoken)
    {
        IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { CalendarService.Scopes.Calendar.GetStringValue() });
        state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
        state.RefreshToken = Refreshtoken;
        return state;
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Where you able to fix this issue? I have the same problem. Thx

Comment: Not yet.

Actually  i want to save the refreshtoken so that i can get a non-expired access token when i make following calls

Comment: Ok but shouldn't this work without tokens. I mean, are you using a key (p.12 - file) and credentials to log in to google API? My code works fine in a Console Application but when i implement the code in Mvc i get this problem. Here's my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144085/error-could-not-load-type-google-apis-authentication-iauthenticator-from-asse

Answer (score 0):

Did you use package manager to install the API?

Further onwards, Are you going to request access everytime or do you want to save the refreshtoken so that you can get a non-expired access token when you make following calls?

Comment: Yes i have used the package manager console to install the api.

and yes i want to save the refreshtoken so that i can get a non-expired access token when i make following calls

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by uninstalling and re-installing the NuGet package "google.apis.auth". This was because multiple versions are installed.

1. Right click on the "References" menu of the project. Manually remove
   all package references related to google.apis.auth.
2. Then, select "Manage NuGet Package", search for "google.apis.auth",
   and uninstall "google.apis.auth".
3. Reinstall the same package.
4. Clean and rebuild

If it doesn't work, you might try reinstall "google.apis" as well.